# Wanted: Instructions for adding client-node encryption enabled Cassandra cluster to DataStax OpsCenter 5.1.0

Tags: ssl, encryption, cassandra, datastax, opscenter

I have a Cassandra cluster with client-node encryption enabled. I am trying to add this cluster to an instance of OpsCenter 5.1.0, but it is not able to connect to the cluster. The log file seems to complain about not being able to verify the SSL certificate:

```
` 
INFO: Starting factory opscenterd.ThriftService.NoReconnectCassandraClientFactory instance at 0x7f2ce05c8638>
2015-06-10 15:09:46+0000 []  WARN: Unable to verify ssl certificate.
2015-06-10 15:09:46+0000 [] Unhandled Error
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/opt/opscenter-5.1.0/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/python/log.py", line 84, in callWithLogger
            return callWithContext({"system": lp}, func, *args, **kw)
          File "/opt/opscenter-5.1.0/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/python/log.py", line 69, in callWithContext
            return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
          File "/opt/opscenter-5.1.0/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/python/context.py", line 59, in callWithContext
            return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
          File "/opt/opscenter-5.1.0/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/python/context.py", line 37, in callWithContext
            return func(*args,**kw)
        --- exception caught here ---
          File "/opt/opscenter-5.1.0/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/epollreactor.py", line 217, in _doReadOrWrite
            why = selectable.doRead()
          File "/opt/opscenter-5.1.0/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 137, in doRead
            return Connection.doRead(self)
          File "/opt/opscenter-5.1.0/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 452, in doRead
            data = self.socket.recv(self.bufferSize)
          File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/SslUtils.py", line 12, in ssl_simple_verifyCB
```

`opscenterd.Utils.SSLVerifyException: SSL certificate invalid`

**My question is: what are the step-by-step instructions for being able to add a client-node encrypted cluster to opscenter? 
Which .pem and .keystore files are needed exactly, how do I get hold of them?**

The DataStax documentation on that topic is not detailed enough and therefore not really helpful. I assume some people out there must have managed to set this up successfully and I am sure that a detailed explanation / instructions would be appreciated by many.

Answer (score 5):

One thing to note here, although the docs do mention generating a key per node, in practice this isn't very scalable. In most systems it is common to create the one keystore with the required keys and certificate(s) and then use this across all the nodes in your cluster and your client applications as needed. You export the certificate from this keystore and use this for OpsCenter. OpsCenter is (as far as SSL is concerned) a SSL client like any other client.

So you have to export your key from your java keystore, convert it to .pem format and use that for the opscenterd process. The agents are java based so they can use the java keystore. The DS docs are there but its a bit fragmented so its a question of looking in the right places :-)

I'm going to use the OpsCenter latest docs here as a reference. I'm assuming you are only using SSL between OpsCenter and Cassandra and OpsCenter Agents and Cassandra

Prepping the server certificates:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/security/secureSSLCertificates_t.html

Configuring client to node SSL:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/security/secureSSLClientToNode_t.html

using cqlsh with SSL (optional):

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/security/secureCqlshSSL_t.html

To convert the key to a pem format see step 7 here:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-opsc/opsc/online_help/opscAddingCluster_t.html

**Examples**

Note all these examples assume 1-way SSL. You generated a key in a file called `/etc/dse/keystore` and the certificate in a file called `/etc/dse/truststore`

To be honest I've never really had a lot of luck in adding SSL enabled clusters directly in the OpsCenter UI. I've always found creating the cluster.conf file and agent address.yaml files by hand far quicker and easier.

Note the SSL files like truststore, key.pem etc need to be on all the local machines that need them.

Example agent `/var/lib/datastax-agent/conf/address.yaml` file (note the `use_ssl` is for the opscenter <> agents SSL which we're not using here)

```
stomp_interface: 192.168.56.29
use_ssl: 0
# ssl_keystore settings if using ssl
ssl_keystore: /etc/dse/truststore
ssl_keystore_password: datastax
```

Example opscenter `/etc/opscenter/clusters/<cluster_name>.conf` file

```
[jmx]
username = 
password = 
port = 7199

[kerberos_client_principals]

[kerberos]

[agents]
ssl_keystore = /etc/dse/truststore
ssl_keystore_password = datastax

[kerberos_hostnames]

[kerberos_services]

[cassandra]
ssl_ca_certs = /etc/dse/key.pem
ssl_validate = False
seed_hosts = 192.168.56.22
```

**Other tips etc**

I always find if Im troubleshooting SSL connections in DSE / Cassandra. I'll strip out all the SSL and get the cluster working nomrmally first, then I'll configure SSL one step at a time, like turning on node to node SSL, then client to node, then OpsCenter and so on. Debugging all the SSL errors is not for the feint hearted!

**Links**

Other doc links you might find useful:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2/opsc/configure/opscConnectionConfig_r.html

https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2/opsc/configure/agentAddressConfiguration.html

Comment: For the **ssl_ca_certs** config that is set in the **<cluster_name>.conf**. Is that key.pem generated from the .cer of that seed node? I'm not sure what .cer or keystore is being used to generate that.

Comment: Should the opscenter server have it's own keystore & .cer generated to add to the truststore? If so, then I'm assuming that I would be using the .pem converted from this .cer as my **ssl_ca_certs**.

Comment: To answer both abover questions. The `key.pem` file is generated from the exported `.cer` file from the keystore on the DSE node. It doesn't matter if it's the seed node as long as you're using the same certificate for both. Usually you'll have the _same_ keystore across the cluster. The documentation infers that you generate a different key for each node but this is not scalable in practice. Hope this helps to answer your questions.

Comment: I'm currently following that docs, so I am generating a keystore file on each node, then creating a .cer for each keystore, which is copied to all nodes. From there, I create the truststore file. In this scenario, is it still ok to just pick one nodes .cer to build a .pem from and use that in opscenter. Or would you recommend using just one keystore for all nodes, and using that .cer and .pem

Comment: You'll probably hit problems there since OpsCenter will need to communication to all the nodes you'll have to import each cer file into each nodes truststore and i dont _think_ you can have the one pem file made up of multiple certificates. Best to go with the one keystore / truststore across the cluster